# Can I include PHP code for IIS deployment in a Chocolatey package?

Tags: nuget-package, chocolatey

Can Chocolatey package source code? We use Subversion for PHP code running on IIS and we currently do an `svn switch` to `c:\inetpub\`. The source includes all the necessary directories like wwwroot and the code.

Could this be done in the nuspec file?

Comment: I was just checking out https://github.com/ferventcoder/chocolatey-packages/blob/master/manual/chucknorris/chucknorris.nuspec   as a possible example of using the <files> file src="SVN checkout location"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't package source code, but it could run svn/git/hg/etc functions to work with source code in the package install script.

It's considered an antipattern to have the source control folders (.svn, .hg, .git, etc) included in the package itself.

Comment: Thanks - went with Inno Setup to create an .exe and was able to create a deployable chocolatey nupkg.